# Chunks R-studio bugged, dont print data-frames. Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Well, i was just mid working in a project and with a new Rmd, and now my chunks dont print my dataframes in the document. If i copy the code in the console it works, tho.

Its curious because i open another archive and they let me do it. In fact most of the code of this defective archive is from other, but this one doesnt work.

I tried to restart, clear outputs, etc, but nothing seems to work.

This are my chunk options at the begin of the document:

````
---
title: "Solo idiopáticos no cov out yes"
author: "Galán del Águila Pacheco Cruz"
date: "19/3/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '5'
    header-includes: \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
header-includes: \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Im kinda new to the reproducibility / session info, so if you could explain to me how i can provide this helpfull info i will provide it ipso-facto.

Comment: Can you paste some of the code that you've tried, including the chunk options at the top? You can print out the `dput` of your data frame by typing `dput(data_frame_name)` into your console.

Comment: Sure, just a sec. Done @Matt

Comment: See my response below

Comment: I just answered your answer. @Matt. It didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your chunk options so that `include = TRUE`:

````
```{r setup, include=TRUE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

You can read more about chunk options [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html),

Comment: No no, its not the knitting options that doesnt work (i didnt even try to knit this), its the chunk itself. It doesnt play any dataframe as it used to work in other rmds. @Matt . And this didnt work either

Comment: Oh... are you trying to use a df that you created in R in an Rmarkdown environment?

Comment: Nope, i just created it and i got it on my envyronement. In fact i can see it if i put it in the console / i go to the environement and click on it so it displays a new tab. Thats why i dont understand whats happening with this cursed file

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without more information. See if you can provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and look into `dput`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Il try to do it as soon as posible. First im going to try to open a new file, to see if its just this (Cause other already finished files work propperly). Fun thing is the knitr also works -_-.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a problem with my pc, or the terminal. Now it works.